# Understanding gi.repository

Tags: python, gtk, matplotlib

I have troubles understanding gi.repository

I use this contruction in my code

```
from gi.repository import Gtk
```

But if I want to use some component I get import error

I searched and I got it worked for some components, like GtkSource, Vte, GLib, ...

So my code is like

```
from gi.repository import Gtk, GtkSource, Vte, GLib
```

Everything worked fine, but if I want to add matplotlib to draw on my canvas I get and error

```
    enter code/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/gtk-2.0/gtk/__init__.py:40: Warning: specified class size for type `PyGtkGenericCellRenderer' is smaller than the parent type's `GtkCellRenderer' class size
  from gtk import _gtk
/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/gtk-2.0/gtk/__init__.py:40: Warning: g_type_get_qdata: assertion `node != NULL' failed
  from gtk import _gtk
/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/gtk-2.0/gtk/__init__.py:40: Warning: g_ascii_strncasecmp: assertion `s2 != NULL' failed
  from gtk import _gtk
Segmentation fault (core dumped) here
```

How can I get matplotlib working with gi.repository?

Thank you

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That's a very good question. I'm afraid the answer might be "you can't." Matplotlib's GTK backend is written for PyGTK, the old-style Python bindings for GTK. The gi.repository package is the new-style Python bindings. I don't know one way or the other whether they can mix or not, but your results seem to indicate they can't.

Comment: 11 months ago a GTK3 backend with the newer gi.repository imports was merged in github: https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/pull/590 I'm not sure what version has this or how exactly to call it, but it *should* be compatible... Unfortunately, as I recently found out, you can't use both imports in the same application, it will crash (segmentation fault).

Answer (score 13):

It seems that the support for Gtk3 it's been [added recently](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/pull/590). I guess it will take some time till it's available in the main distributions.

The best solution would be to download and install the latest version.

As a workaround to avoid installing stuff in my Ubuntu 11.10 I have [dowloaded backend_gtk3.py and backend_gtk3agg.py files](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/blob/master/lib/matplotlib/backends) and imported directly like:

```
from gi.repository import Gtk

from matplotlib.figure import Figure
from backend_gtk3agg import FigureCanvasGTK3Agg as FigCanvas
```

I had to change backend_gtk3agg.py line 6 where it says:

```
import backend_agg
```

with

```
from matplotlib.backends import backend_agg
```

, so it can import the module from my installation.
So far it works for me, but I understand this solution can't work with different versions of matplotlib.

Comment: Hi, are you saying that you just downloaed two files? I am trying this example: http://matplotlib.org/dev/examples/user_interfaces/embedding_in_gtk3.html using the procedure you explain but it does not work. Could you please elaborate a little more. Also do you use Figure from the local matplotlib installation or not?